# jQuery: Do I need both keyUp and change events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with 2 forms; each form has an input text field;

The value found in the input text of the 1st form must be the same with the value found in the input text of the 2nd form;

When the value changes, the other input text field also modifies its value;

Should I use both `onkeyup` and `onchange` events?

If not, which one is the right one to use?

I am asking this because it seams that I have 2 post requests, and I think that this is why.

```
   $('input.searchbox').keyup( function(){
       $('input.txtfieldsearch').val($('input.searchbox').val());
       listViewUpdate();
       $('input.txtfieldsearch').trigger("keyup");
   });
                
    $('input.txtfieldsearch').keyup( function(){
       $('input.searchbox').val($('input.txtfieldsearch').val());
       listViewUpdate();
    });
                
   $('input.searchbox').change( function(){
       $('input.txtfieldsearch').val($('input.searchbox').val());
       listViewUpdate();
       $('input.txtfieldsearch').trigger("change");
   });
                
    $('input.txtfieldsearch').change( function(){
       $('input.searchbox').val($('input.txtfieldsearch').val());
       listViewUpdate();
    });
```

Comment: but wich one is the right to use?

Comment: When do you *want* the values to update? `change` and `keyup` are different events, and you might use both of them.

Comment: Did you notice that you're calling `listViewUpdate` twice from the `searchbox`?

Comment: yes I did; 1st for keyup; 2nd for change

Comment: No, I meant twice for each event. You trigger the handler on the `txtfieldsearch` as well which will execute `listViewUpdate` again.

Comment: yes, true, this might be one of the problem, possible answer

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function and attach **multiples handlers**.

```
$("#element").on('keyup change', function (){
   // Your stuff...
});
```

Comment: this calls the event callback twice.

Comment: I never found a solution that didn't call the event callback twice. I eventually settled on a hack to remove the increment arrows from my input using css which forces keyup usage in my case:

`/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
`

Answer (score 12):

You can use only "input" event if you don't need to provide support for the older browsers. It will be fired everytime a value changes in the input element. Here's a list of the supported browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Answer (score 11):

[`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) mostly fires when a key was pressed by the user and then released. [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) can happen if the user uses the browser's autocomplete feature. You should use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to catch both events, just in case:

```
$('input.searchbox').on('keyup change', function(e){
    $('input.txtfieldsearch').val($('input.searchbox').val());
    listViewUpdate();
    $('input.txtfieldsearch').trigger(e.type);
});

$('input.txtfieldsearch').on('keyup change', function(){
    $('input.searchbox').val($('input.txtfieldsearch').val());
    listViewUpdate();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to react to change, you should use `change`.

There are some occasions where a keyup doesn't make a change(like shift) and occasions where there's a change without a keyup (paste).

Comment: does this mean that i am doing it the right way if i have used `keyup` and `change` ?

Comment: Keyup seldom makes a change. `change` will only fire if you blur the input field.

Comment: They do different things. You should try them separately and see when they fire and see which is the one you need. In some cases, both may be correct.